# How do you create a reactive dataframe (populated with streaming data) in Deedle?

Tags: f#, reactive-programming, deedle

I want to create a dataframe which would contain streaming data. How is this done in Deedle?

The amount of data rows is not known in advance hence I want to create something like an Rx stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that Deedle does not currently have support for streaming data.

You can definitely use something like Rx or [F# asynchronous sequences](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-sequences.aspx/) to collect data reactively and then pass them to Deedle (once you have a chunk you want to process) but that's not going to be very optimal. Another interesting project to look at is [Naiad LINQ](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/naiad/) which sounds like exactly what you need.

There is definitely some interest in using Deedle with streaming data, and we've been thinking about how to do that - the design of Deedle is fairly extensible so there might be a way to do this. If you're interested in contributing, check out the [design notes document](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/design.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Perhaps Deedle can inherit some Rx/Naiad like functionality in the future.